# Science fiction book series with characters using cards to move between space

Tags: story-identification

I don't remember much, but the main characters were from a feudal world that had knights and dukes, moving between today's world and an ancient universe using a card game or something like that. What is the title of book series?

Comment: same answer as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/100829/story-about-a-boy-man-who-was-driven-into-another-world-to-save-someone-brother/100830#100830 (from yesterday)

Comment: see more expansive question and answer on same series at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/157562/story-identification-fantasy-world-that-is-the-one-true-world

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You're probably thinking of Roger Zelazny's [Amber series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chronicles_of_Amber), which has characters from a vaguely feudal setup communicating with each other and moving to each other via cards called Trumps, and includes many parallel realities of which ours is one.

Comment: This is exactly the series I was thinking of.  It matches the OP's description perfectly.

Comment: Yep. If names like Corwin and Dierdre and Brand and Fiona and Dworkin and "The Pattern" ring a bell, that's it. :)